# Power supply for a device

Tags: power-supply

I have a device and the datasheet says the power supply must be a 1.5V AC(Max sine) with an operating frequency of 500Hz-2kHz. Does the 1.5V AC(Max sine) mean that supply is a sine wave with peaks of -1.5V to +1.5V? or is the 1.5V value an RMS value?
I Have attached an image of the specifications below, as well as a link to the datasheet.
https://www.elecrow.com/download/HR202%20Humidity%20Sensor.pdf

[image: Screenshot of Specifications here]

I want to simulate it and i cuurently have it as 1.5 peak to peak at a frequency of 1000Hz

Comment: Why not tell us what the device is and post a link to the datasheet? Add them into your question, not in the comments.

Comment: okay, I just thought the specifications would be fine, but ill put the link in now. Thanks!

Comment: Since they're giving impedance vs. voltage in their table, it is very likely to RMS.  Using peak to peak with impedance would be misleading.

Comment: @HraklisPapageorgiou - Hi, I see that you deleted a previous question about the same sensor ("[LCR AC bridge for a humidity sensor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/525009)") *even though someone had taken the time and trouble to write an answer for you!* (Unfortunately no-one had upvoted the answer before you deleted the question, otherwise you would not have been able to delete it). Although the site allowed you to delete your question in that case (and therefore delete the answer), please think hard before doing that, as it prevents future readers from learning from that Q&A. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specifications say:

- Power supply: 1.5 V AC (**Max sine**)
- Operating frequency: 500 Hz - 2 kHz
- Rated power: 0.2 mW (Max sine)
- Central value: 31 kΩ (at 25 Celsius, 1 kHz ,**1 V AC**, 60% RH)

I would take the first to be 1.5 V peak and the second to be RMS. Given that a 1 Vrms sine would peak at \$ \sqrt 2\$ times the RMS value that would make sense.

As a second check look at their power rating for the central value - it's 31 kΩ at 1 V (RMS, we assume). From \$ P = \frac {V^2} R = \frac {1^2}{31k} = 30 \ \mu\text {W} \$ all would be fine.

[image]

*Figure 1. Resistance vs RH.*

Worst case will be at minimum resistance. At 90% RH the resistance falls to 2 kΩ. Calculating again we get \$ P = \frac {V^2} R = \frac {1^2}{2k} = 500 \ \mu\text {W} \$. At this point you are 2.5 times the rated power. Not so good.

I'd use the max rated power figure, the resistance for your worst-case %RH and work out your Vrms from that.